# Remove duplicated IDs from value results

Tags: codeigniter

The platform is: codeigniter.

I have a row comments in database that contains all comments to ads.
The comments row has ID, ads ID, the comment, the response to comment:

[image]

My issue is with duplicated comment on the ads, so if the user puts a comment to an ad, the script will reply to him with text "thanks for comment".

As you can see (random users have the ability to comment on my ad)
the commenter_id = 112 is comment more than once, and it will cause the server overload.

My code is like this:

```
$comment_list = $this->basic->get_all_comment_of_ads($adsid);
$commenter_count=isset($comment_list["commenter_info"]) ? count($comment_list["commenter_info"]) : 0 ;
if(isset($comment_list["commenter_info"]))
       {
          if(isset($comment_list["commenter_info"][$ad_account_id])) 
          {
            $commenter_count--; // if ad account is also commenter
            unset($comment_list["commenter_info"][$ad_account_id]);
          }
       }
```

So the result `$commenter_count` will be 3 in this example (5 - 2 duplictated).

How do I prevent response to the comment from the same commenter_id?

I tried to do:

```
$i=0;
$commenter_info=array();
foreach($comment_list as $info){
 $time=  isset($info['created_time'])?(array)$info['created_time']:"";
 $comment_info[$i]['created_time']=isset($time['date'])?$time['date']:"";
 $comment_info[$i]['commenter_name']=isset($info['from']['name'])? $info['from']['name']:"";
 $comment_info[$i]['commenter_id']=isset($info['from']['id'])?$info['from']['id']:"";
 $comment_info[$i]['message']=isset($info['commente_text'])?$info['message']:"";
 $comment_info[$i]['comment_id']=isset($info['id'])?$info['id']:"";
 /* Store Commenter info as unique */
 if(!isset($commenter_info[$comment_info[$i]['commenter_id']])){
 $commenter_info[$comment_info[$i]['commenter_id']]['name']=$comment_info[$i]['commenter_name'];
 $commenter_info[$comment_info[$i]['commenter_id']]['last_comment']=$comment_info[$i]['message'];
 $commenter_info[$comment_info[$i]['commenter_id']]['last_comment_id']=$comment_info[$i]['comment_id'];
 $commenter_info[$comment_info[$i]['commenter_id']]['last_comment_time']=$comment_info[$i]['created_time'];
    }
    $i++;
}
```

but it will return to commenter count (3).

I stopped at this point, and I can't get the logic on how to get the commenter_id and store it to check if the commenter_id is duplicated and not replied him anymore after first time replied.

I looked into most replied, but it did not help my case.

Answer (score 0):

The answer here I believe you're after is a `UNIQUE` index on the `commenter_id` column (assuming MySQL). Assuming you are using Codeigniter 4, you can then do something like this:

```
$db = $this->db->table('comments');

$db->set([
'commenter_id'  => '',
'adsid'     => '',
'commente_text' => '',
'response_to_text'  => ''
]);

$db->ignore(true);
$db->insert();
```

Note your `ignore(true)` is the key here. This does something like this in mysql:

`INSERT IGNORE INTO comments ...`

So will basically ignore the row if a user has already added a comment (i.e.
an element with the same DB Key). However you should factor in that a user may want to `update` their comment instead!! In which case you would call the `update()` function and use `WHERE` to update the record rather than ignore it.

Comment: thanks @Antony  for your answer, i tried this, but the random users are commenting very fast to overload my server, the script is  not sending data to the DB immediately after commenting ( i mean not fast enough to prevent the user from commenting again and again ) . so if the user comments quickly for example 6 times in a row, the script will respond to him every time ( i tested it by myself and it responded to me 6 times before knowing that i am a duplicated user ) 
so that i have this controller get_all_comment_of_ads that fetched data from the ad itself immediately .

Comment: My suggestion would be look in the console log (network tab) on your browser and do 1 single submission and see how many rows it creates. From the sounds of it there may be something wrong with your code / javascript as the comments are the same its possible you are sending multiple queries as opposed to users doing it. You could find you're doing a jquery on() and its re-binding the same events re-triggering a post. I have certainly had that in my time!